# Apply a function only if isJust

Tags: haskell

I am looking for a idiomatic way of doing

```
moveMaybeCreature Nothing world = world
moveMaybeCreature (Just creature) world = moveCreature creature world
```

Or in other words

```
if isJust c
    then doSomething (fromJust c) w
    else w
```

I thought I could to it this way:

```
moveMaybeCreature c w = foldr moveCreature w (maybeToList c)
```

Can I do it without having to convert `Maybe Creature` to `[Creature]`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this as long as type of `world` and `moveCreature (fromJust c) world` are same. You can use `maybe` from `Data.Maybe`.

```
 moveMaybeCreature = maybe id moveCreature
```

Your first way of doing where you pattern match should also work just fine.

Comment: That's the very first function described on the doc for Data.Maybe, and I somehow missed it.  Thanks!

Comment: As a side note, there's also the equivalent for `Either`: `either` in `Data.Either`.

Comment: Your precondition on the types is pretty much guaranteed if `moveMaybeCreature` typechecked in the first place...

Comment: @BenMillwood Yeah I know that it will be asserted by the typechecker. I just wanted to specify that you can not do this if you wanted to return different types for `Nothing` and `Just c`.

Comment: But there's no way to do that regardless of what method you use, so it's a redundant condition.

Answer (score 6):

I second the recommendation to use the `maybe` function. You were right to ask this question because of this general rule of thumb (not just for you, but for any newcomers reading it): functions with types like `Maybe Foo -> Bar` or `Maybe Foo -> Maybe Bar` that are defined directly are a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) in Haskell.  You almost never want to write a function that takes `Maybe Foo` as an argument; you want a function that takes just `Foo`, and use a higher-order function to adapt it to `Maybe Foo`.

Suppose you have a function `f' :: Maybe Foo -> Maybe Bar`.  This can usually be refactored into either:

1. `f :: Foo -> Bar` and `fmap f :: Maybe Foo -> Maybe Bar`;
2. `f :: Foo -> Maybe Bar` and `(>>=f) :: Maybe Foo -> Maybe Bar`

First case works because this is the `Functor` instance for `Maybe`:

```
instance Functor Maybe where
    fmap f Nothing = Nothing
    fmap f (Just x) = Just (f x)

-- or this:
--     fmap f = maybe Nothing (Just . f)
```

Second case works because this is the `Monad` instance for `Maybe`:

```
instance Monad Maybe where
    return = Just
    Nothing >>= f = Nothing
    (Just x) >>= f = f x

-- or this:
--     mx >>= f = maybe Nothing f mx
```

Comment: .... and as Satvik said, if you have a function of type `Maybe a -> b` like yours, you can use the `maybe` function to refactor it.

Comment: Interestingly, if you're writing a function like `perhaps :: a -> b -> Maybe c -> Maybe d -> Maybe e -> Maybe f`, you can use Applicative and write the pure bit assuming all the maybe data is available, and define `perhaps = purebit a b <$> c <*> d <*> e`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another option, closer to your original code:

```
import qualified Data.Foldable as F

moveMaybeCreature = flip (F.foldr moveCreature)
```